# Can't convert .ass to .srt using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, srt

So when I tried to convert .ass subtitles to .srt, ffmpeg threw this error:

```
Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)
```

The command I used for the conversion was this:

```
ffmpeg -i subtitles.ass -c:s srt subtitles.srt
```

I also tried:

```
ffmpeg -i subtitles.ass subtitles.srt
```

And:

```
ffmpeg -i subtitles.ass -codec:s text subtitles.srt
```

My .ass file seems fine, I ran `chardetect` and the output was `utf-8 with confidence 0.99`

Comment: Does ffmpeg give you any error output? You can try your luck with apps like Subtitled Pro, which does ASS import and SRT export. Better option is to debug where ffmpeg is choking. You can get some useful debug information this way:
`ffmpeg -i subtitles.ass -loglevel debug -c:s srt subtitles.srt`

Answer (score 1):

I did this,

```bash
$ ffmpeg -i op1062.ass -codec:s srt op1062.srt
ffmpeg version 6.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/6.0 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
  libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavformat    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavdevice    60.  1.100 / 60.  1.100
  libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100
  libswscale      7.  1.100 /  7.  1.100
  libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100
  libpostproc    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
Input #0, ass, from 'op1062.ass':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Subtitle: ass
Output #0, srt, to 'op1062.srt':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf60.3.100
  Stream #0:0: Subtitle: subrip
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc60.3.100 srt
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (ass (ssa) -> subrip (srt))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
size=      19kB time=00:23:45.89 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s speed=1.6e+05x
video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:13kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 46.724522%
```

and this was the result,

```bash
$ ll
total 80
-rw-r--r--  1 ihsanpraditya  staff    20K May 25 22:13 op1062.ass
-rw-r--r--  1 ihsanpraditya  staff    19K May 25 22:39 op1062.srt
```

I checked it in Jubler,
[image: Jubler]

I had tried it at [IINA](https://iina.io/) and it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
ffmpeg -i source.mkv -map 0 -c:s srt -vn -an -dn srt_subs.mkv
```